# VS.NET - Add in for automatically formatting C# code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, add-in, code-formatting

Is there any VS.NET add in for formatting C# as you type based on the given rules?

Except for [ReSharper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#ReSharper_Ultimate), as it does so many other things and slows down VS.NET due to that, so I'm looking for a light add-in just for code formatting.

Comment: I just came across [codemaid](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/76293c4d-8c16-4f4a-aee6-21f83a571496) a few minutes ago.

Comment: @xecaps12 seems like it's not doing code formatting as user type

Comment: I don't feel ReSharper is slowing down my system that much.

Comment: No, it's not automatic. You do have to invoke it by either the shortcut or selecting from the menu.

Answer (score 0):

The [Continuous Formatting](https://vlasovstudio.com/continuous-formatting/) extension formats C# code automatically as you type. To give rules you can use the built-in Visual Studio engine or external tools like ReSharper and [CodeRush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodeRush).